Iterate over two string columns to find if one appears in the other
I am new to Python and trying to find a way of comparing one column of strings to another column of strings for the length of the dataset. I would like to create a binary variable as the result to answer if the one string was found within the other.
data = {
    'col_one': ['truck', 'car', 'bike', 'boat', 'scooter'],
    'col_two': ["['truck', 'boat']", "['bike', 'boat', 'car']",
                "['scooter']", "['truck', 'car']", "['bike', 'car']"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

I have tried code like this to search a Column Two string for a Column One string and have had success:
import re

def comp_strs(str1, str2):
    pattern = re.compile(str1)
    match = re.search(pattern, str2)
    if match:
        print('Found')
    else:
        print('Not found')

str1 = "Truck"
str2 = "'Truck', 'Boat'"
comp_strs(str1, str2)

However, I am struggling to expand on this to use the Column_one and Column_two inputs rather than individual strings as well as iterate through the length of the columns/length of the dataframe and store the binary result in a new column.

There are no lists in your dataframe. col_two contains strings that are the representation of lists.

@barmar - I do not believe this qualifies as a duplicate question since, the col_two data is not formatted in a way that the answers of the "original" question will solve.

Your re.search() version doesn't depend on any special formatting.

@OysterShucker How so? df.apply(lambda row: row['col_one'] in row['col_two'], axis=1) returns True, True, False, False, False, which is what OP wants (or seems to at least).

@user24645857 It'd help to add your desired output. I think it's obvious by reading closely, "if the one string was found within the other", but it helps to be explicit.
